# Insert data in different table in one submit using Struts2 and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am having a jsp with the following fields :
 `loginID`,`password`,`firstName`,`lastName`,`aadharCardNo`,`standard`,`section`,`schoolName`

where `loginID`,`password`,`firstName`,`lastName` are from table `u_user`

`aadharCardNo` is from `u_userdocument`

`standard`,`section`,`schoolName` is from `u_academicdetails`

As soon as the user enters all the details in register.jsp page a ID(generated ID after submitting the form) is generated and following insertions should take place in respective tables

`aadharCardNo`,`ID`(generated one) in `u_userdocument`

`standard`,`section`,`schoolName`,`ID`(generated one) in `u_academicdetails`

and `firstName`,`lastName`,`ID`(generated one) in `u_user`

How I am able to do this in Hibernate???

Please suggest me , as I am new to Hibernate and not able to figure this out after various trials.!!!

I have mapped the tables using one-to-one mapping...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:
Create extra fields in user table, containing the information needed to save to other tables. Hibernate insert only works when mapping from other tables, that constraint made me do this.

You can instantiate your other models in UserDAO. Then set their parameters from the user table you just mapped to in your action, then save the session as you normally would. Here is registrate from my UserDAO. roleName was a parameter meant for a roleName table, however I mapped it into User so I could copy it across.

Please note that this is probably a hack.

```
public void registrate(Session session, String email, String plainTextPassword, String roleName) {
    User user = new User();
    UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
    user.setUsername(email);
    user.setEmail(email);
    generatePassword(user, plainTextPassword);
    user.setRoleName(roleName);

    userRole.setEmail(email);
    userRole.setRoleName(roleName);
    session.save(user);
    session.save(userRole);
    //Query query = session.createQuery("insert into UserRole(roleName, email) select email,roleName from User where roleName =:roleName and email =:email");
    //query.setParameter("roleName", roleName);
    //query.setParameter("email", email);
    //query.executeUpdate();        
}
```

My form:

```
<div>
    <s:form action="createUser" method="post">
    E-Mail
    <s:textfield name="email" key="user.email"/>
    Password
    <s:textfield name="password" key="user.password"/>
    Role name
    <s:textfield name="roleName" key="user.roleName"/>
    <br/>
    <s:submit />
    </s:form>
```

Comment: I had used one-to-one mapping of hibernate but I want to send data through JSP, how can I name the variables of different tables in jsp, I am using ModelDriven class for my struts action